# Accessing Google Chrome V8 engine console remotely

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, v8

I have a NodeJS application running on a server in forever mode and the **console.log** outputs from the application scripts are logged into the directory **~/.forever/** (as this is in the root directory, only read permissions are available to the log file in this directory). These logs are displayed in the server's chrome browser v8 engine's console through node-monkey at the address **127.0.0.1:50500**.

This server is behind a proxy.

Now, I want to see this logs from the server's V8 engine on a client browser. I tried to access it using the server's address followed by the port as below from the browser, but wasn't able to connect.

http://www.servers.addr.com:50500

I have also tried connecting to the server through ssh and performing **curl** on the command line to the localhost address above, but *as expected* it would only fetch the html content displayed in the browsers window.

So is there any way we can fetch the console logs from the v8 engine of the browser running in the server.

Comment: I guess you could use a rewrite, such as with nginx, to rewrite `http://console.servers.addr.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:50500`. No idea if it would work.

Comment: I haven't used nginx, can you elaborate more? I want to access the browser console running on server from a client.

Comment: are you using any front to your node apps? apache? iis? something else? for all i know it can be done with linux alone, not too familiar with linux yet. just enough to be dangerous.

Comment: No, the application is run by node itself. And the server is ubuntu.

Comment: In one of my node apps, I just created a route with code behind it that creates a page to view the logs so I can just put that URL into my browser and get a page that shows me the logs.  Your node server won't show them unless you add code to some route to provide access to the logs.

Comment: nginx is pretty easy to install/setup. there's plenty of guides around, no point in me elaborating more on that. one of the existing guides will probably do better than i can.

Comment: well jfriend00, creating a new route implies we have to modify the application, and I would prefer to do it when no other option is available.

and @KevinB, I will check nginx :)

Comment: Note that you'll likely want to change your node app to another port and serve it with nginx too so that multiple apps can all be served from port 80 externally.

Comment: Node isn't going to serve up something that you haven't told it to - if it could do that, this would be an enormous security hole which is why it can't be done that way.  So, your only two choices are to have some other server serve up the logs or modify your node app to serve up the logs.  Pick which one you want.  If you want, you can just login to your ubuntu server remotely and look directly at the file system.  Anything else requires setting up something new to offer access to what would normally be protected content.  I found it easier to add 10 lines of code to my app for a new route.

Comment: jfriend00, I understand. But I would like to access the logs that are output by the node-monkey on the server localhost, broswer's console.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks for suggesting nginx, now able to access it remotely :)